# Analyzing anomalies of Bluetooth audio generation with Mathematica

Tags: interpolation, fourier-analysis

I' m working on an audio generator for physics lab, using an Android device and Bluetooth . However, the response of the Bluetooth speaker is wrong.
When programmed to deliver, say 3150 Hz, it may actually generate fBT =  3145.73 Hz.

I will actually implement the solution in C#. The following Mathematica code is just meant as a prototype.

The following is how I measure frequency:

```
SR = 1764; (* A sample rate *)
fBT = 3145.730; (*Anomalous BT frequency*)
(* Create a test audio signal with the anomalous Bluetooth frequency.*)
testSignal[k_] := Sin[2*Pi*fBT*(k - 1)/SR];
c1Sinf[f_] := Sum[testSignal[k]*Sin[2*Pi*f*((k - 1)/SR)], {k, 1, SR}]; 
c1Cosf[f_] := Sum[testSignal[k]*Cos[2*Pi*f*((k - 1)/SR)], {k, 1, SR}]; 
d1Sinf[f_] := Sum[2*Pi*((k - 1)/SR)*testSignal[k]*Cos[2*Pi*f*((k - 1)/SR)], {k, 1, SR}]; 
d1Cosf[f_] := -Sum[
    2*Pi*((k - 1)/SR)*testSignal[k]*Sin[2*Pi*f*((k - 1)/SR)], {k, 1, 
     SR}]; 
s2c2[f_] := c1Sinf[f]^2 + c1Cosf[f]^2; 
dTotal[f_] := 2*c1Sinf[f]*d1Sinf[f] + 2*c1Cosf[f]*d1Cosf[f];
```

First, I try to identify fBT with the geometrical construct below.
Note the blue line at the center, corresponding to the anomalous BT frequency.

```
(*ATTENTION: The red lines don't represent actual measurements; they just connect sampled points.*)
p1 = DiscretePlot[s2c2[f], {f, 3145, 3146, 0.05}, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, InfiniteLine[{fBT, 0}, {0, 1}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{3145.5, 3146}, {760000, 780000}}];
(* Plot a tangent on a close point. *)

p2 = Plot[
   s2c2[3145.7] + dTotal[3145.7]*(f - 3145.7), {f, 3145.6, 3146}, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange];
(* Plot another tangent. *)

p3 = Plot[
   s2c2[3145.75] + dTotal[3145.75]*(f - 3145.75), {f, 3145.6, 3145.8},
    PlotStyle -> Orange];
(* Plot "underlying" frequency transform", red, dashed. *)

p4 = Plot[s2c2[f], {f, 3145.6, 3145.9}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
(* Plot the maximum (manual observation). *)

p5 = Plot[s2c2[fBT], {f, 3145.6, 3145.9}, PlotStyle -> Green];
(* Plot a base line *)

p6 = Plot[s2c2[3145.7], {f, 3145.7, 3145.8}, PlotStyle -> Purple];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]
```

[image: Trying to make geometrical construction for identifying BT frequency.]

Here we plot more points.

```
p1 = DiscretePlot[s2c2[f], {f, 3145, 3146, 0.015}, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, InfiniteLine[{fBT, 0}, {0, 1}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{3145.5, 3146}, {760000, 780000}}];
p2 = Plot[
   s2c2[3145.7] + dTotal[3145.7]*(f - 3145.7), {f, 3145.6, 3146}, 
   PlotStyle -> Orange];
p3 = Plot[
   s2c2[3145.75] + dTotal[3145.75]*(f - 3145.75), {f, 3145.6, 3145.8},
    PlotStyle -> Orange];
p4 = Plot[s2c2[f], {f, 3145.6, 3145.9}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
p5 = Plot[s2c2[fBT], {f, 3145.6, 3145.9}, PlotStyle -> Green];
p6 = Plot[s2c2[3145.7], {f, 3145.7, 3145.8}, PlotStyle -> Purple];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6]
```

[image: Another attempt to geometrically identify fBT.]

I would like to ask:

- Is it possible to make a geometrical construction with derivatives
  to identify the BT frequency?
- I think Newton's method would work in this problem, but I want to know if there's
  something shorter.
- It is also possible to characterize the frequency response by
  taking the derivative of the Fourier transform, like the figure below
  shows.
  It seems easy enough to find the cross by zero at fBT, but I haven't
  seen this method often. What are advantages/disadvantages of this
  method?

```
p10 = DiscretePlot[dTotal[f], {f, 3145, 3146, 0.1}, 
   Epilog -> InfiniteLine[{fBT, 0}, {0, 1}]];
p20 = Plot[dTotal[f], {f, 3145, 3146}];
Show[p10, p20]
```

[image]

Comment: You might try using `Interpolation` with your data to create an `InterpolationFunction` and then use `FindMaximum` to determine the frequency.